# Build from external GIT repo located in networkshare

Tags: tfs-2015

I have problem to create service connection under TFS2015 Update2.
I have GIT remote REPO located in server and i access it by network share folder in this format:

```
\\server\GIT_REPOS\GIT_REPO_TO_BUILD_FROM\
```

I tried add new External GIT REPO Connection under TFS configuration as follow:

```
Connection name: Git repo
Server url: \\server\GIT_REPOS\GIT_REPO_TO_BUILD_FROM\
UserName: domain\username
Password: userPassword
```

When I try queue new build i get this error:

```
Failed to resolve path 'file://server/GIT_REPOS/GIT_REPO_TO_BUILD_FROM/': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Prepare repository failed with exception.
```

Know someone correct way how to use it with network shared REPO ?

Thanks for help a lot.

Comment: Have you published the repository to TFS?

Comment: No. In few situations we use git repo locayed outside of tfs.

Comment: Is the remote repository managed by a Git server? Or it is just a local repo on that server machine?

Comment: I think is local repo located on server machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to website https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html, Git supports Local protocol and can use the path to the repository as the URL, but in TFS build, local path isn't supported (I got the same error as you).

As an alternate, you need to publish your repo to a server. Meanwhile, you may consider submit a UserVoice at website https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015 to specify the requirement of supporting local git.

Comment: I do not want to use tfs repo, but external git. So I think my story is not supported.

Comment: So why is this called External GIT ? For me meaning EXTERNAL is that repo is located outside of TFS and noone should care where... if in other TFS or ...

Comment: I'm sorry that I have misunderstood your scenario before. You are right that you need to specify an URL, there is not an UNC path option.

Comment: And do you know about any workaround how to have local repo accessible by HTTP/S protocol ? like 3rd party tool what will handle communication or something ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. According to website https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html, Git supports Local protocol and can use the path to the repository as the URL, but in TFS build, local path seems not support (I got the same error as you). As an alternate, you need to publish your repo to a server. Meanwhile, you may consider submit a UserVoice at website https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015 to specify the requirement of supporting local git.

Comment: The problem is I can not publish repo to TFS :/ ...anyway thanks for help :) \

Comment: You can also try to publish it to other version-controlled system.

Comment: i have to let it be in repo where it is ...i can publish directly to tfs git but this is not acceptable in our scenario

Comment: I recommend you submit a UserVoice at website https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015 o specify the requirement of supporting local git. Product Team will evaluate it seriously.